# Deleting function not working and no errors appear

Tags: reactjs, firebase, jsx, crud

Good day so I have a question about firebase and perhaps my code as well I wrote some code in JSX and React linked to Firebase and the Button that I'm using to delete is not working properly.

I'm using Parent Child props to pass the function into the page that is needed to be deleted but there is no functionality. I need help thanks!

this is the parent where the function is located :

```
import React from 'react';
import fire from '../config/firebase';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
// import "firebase/database";
// import 'firebase/auth';

import NotesCard from './note-card';

Modal.setAppElement('#root');


export default class Notes extends React.Component {
  _isMounted = false;
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      notes: [],
      showModal: false,
      loggedin: false
    };
    this.handleOpenModal = this.handleOpenModal.bind(this);
    this.handleCloseModal = this.handleCloseModal.bind(this);
    this.handleAddNote = this.handleAddNote.bind(this);
    this.handleRemoveNote = this.handleRemoveNote.bind(this);

  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;

    fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if(user){
        // call firebase from import fire 
        // grab userData and push it to the dataArray
        fire.database().ref(`users/${user.uid}/notes`).on('value', (res) => {
          const userData = res.val()
          const dataArray = []
          for(let objKey in userData) {
            userData[objKey].key = objKey
            dataArray.push(userData[objKey])
          }
          // set in the state 
          if(this._isMounted){
            this.setState({
            notes: dataArray,
            loggedin: true
            })
          }
        });
      }else {
        this.setState({loggedin: false})

      }
    });
  };

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
  }

  handleAddNote (e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    const note = {
      title: this.noteTitle.value,
      text: this.noteText.value
    }
    // reference where we can push it
    const userId = fire.auth().currentUser.uid;
    const dbRef = fire.database().ref(`users/${userId}/notes`);
    dbRef.push(note)

    this.noteTitle.value = ''
    this.noteText.value = ''
    this.handleCloseModal()
  }

  handleRemoveNote(key) {
    const userId = fire.auth().currentUser.uid;
    const dbRef = fire.database().ref(`users/${userId}/notes/${key}`);
    dbRef.remove();
  }

  handleOpenModal (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      showModal: true
    });
  }

  handleCloseModal () {
    this.setState({
      showModal: false
    });
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleOpenModal}>create Note</button>
        <section className='notes'>
          {
            this.state.notes.map((note, indx) => {
              return (
                <NotesCard 
                  note={note} 
                  key={`note-${indx}`} 
                  handleRemoveNote={this.handleRemoveNote}
                /> 
              )
            }).reverse()
          }
        </section>
        <Modal
        isOpen={this.state.showModal}
        onRequestClose={this.handleCloseModal}
        shouldCloseOnOverlayClick={false}
        style={
          {
            overlay: {
              backgroundColor: '#9494b8'
            },
            content: {
              color: '#669999'
            }
          }
        }
        >
          <form onSubmit={this.handleAddNote}>
            <h3>Add New Note</h3>
            <label htmlFor='note-title'>Title:</label>
            <input type='text' name='note-title' ref={ref => this.noteTitle = ref} />
            <label htmlFor='note-text'>Note</label>
            <textarea name='note-text' ref={ref => this.noteText = ref} placeholder='type notes here...' />
            <input type='submit' onClick={this.handleAddNote} />
            <button onClick={this.handleCloseModal}>close</button>
          </form>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

and this is where the function is being called :

```
import React from 'react';
import fire from '../config/firebase';

export default class NotesCard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      editing: false,
      note: {}
    }
    this.handleEditNote = this.handleEditNote.bind(this);
    this.handleSaveNote = this.handleSaveNote.bind(this);
  }

  handleEditNote() {
    this.setState({
      editing: true
    })
  }

  handleSaveNote(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const userId = fire.auth().currentUser.uid;
    const dbRef = fire.database().ref(`users/${userId}/notes/${this.props.note.key}`);
    dbRef.update({
      title: this.noteTitle.value,
      text: this.noteText.value
    })
    this.setState({
      editing: false
    })
  }

  render() {
    let editingTemp = (
      <span>
        <h4>{this.props.note.title}</h4>
        <p>{this.props.note.text}</p>
      </span>
    )
    if(this.state.editing) {
      editingTemp = (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSaveNote}>
          <div>
            <input 
              type='text' 
              defaultValue={this.props.note.title} 
              name='title' 
              ref={ref => this.noteTitle = ref}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input 
              type='text' 
              defaultValue={this.props.note.text} 
              name='text' 
              ref ={ref => this.noteText = ref}
            />
          </div>
          <input type='submit' value='done editing' />
        </form>
      )

    }
    
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleEditNote}>edit</button>
        <button onClick={this.props.handleRemoveNote(this.state.note.key)}>delete</button>
        {editingTemp}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance for taking a look at this code.

Comment: could you please create a code sandbox example of the problem?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-knuth-2og8e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Second iteration answer

### Working sandbox

[image: Edit condescending-night-8jkrj]

### Problem

looking at https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-knuth-2og8e?file=/src/components/note-card.js:1621-1708

I see that you have this line

> <button onClick={()=> this.props.handleRemoveNote(**this.state.note.key**)}>delete

Yet your state.note declared as an empty map in the  constructor:

```js
 this.state = {
   editing: false,
   note: {}
}
```

**But never assigned a value using this.setState in the component**

### Solution

Change it to:

```js
<button onClick={()=> this.props.handleRemoveNote(**this.props.note.key**)}>delete</button>
```

### First iteration answer

NotesCard's buttons is firing the onClick callback on render instead on click event.
This is because you have executed the function instead of passing a callback to the onClick handler

Change

```
<button onClick={this.props.handleRemoveNote(this.state.note.key)}>delete</button>
```

To

```
<button onClick={()=> this.props.handleRemoveNote(this.state.note.key)}>delete</button>
```

Comment: thanks for answering so quickly but I changed it and it still doesn't do the function

Comment: any ideas what ight be wrong? I still can't figure it out

Comment: could you supply login for the app?

Comment: username : ignatius.and@gmail.com

Comment: password: password

Comment: thank you for taking the time again @Itamar this was very helpful,